# Add Page Model in ASP .Net Framework to an existing page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to add a page model (PageName.cshtml.cs) to an existing page (PageName.cshtml) in my MVC Web App .NET Framework, but i have no idea how to do it.
I have an UserModel.cs that has "Age" properties, but the problem is that in "Create" or "Edit" form I don't want to get the age with an integer input, but I would like to get it via a new "BirthDate" field getted by datepicker input. This field should be independent from UserModel.
Briefly, the questions are:

1. If it is possible, how can I add a page model to an existing page ?
2. If it isn't possibile or I can add this field in other way, what do you suggest to do ?

Comment: Are you talking about partial views

Comment: yes you can, just create class name: UserViewModel.cs and replace age integer to datetime.